# Back button doesn't re-trigger backbone app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, marionette

I'm running into a weird scenario in my Backbone Marionette app. If a user clicks on the facebook/twitter link and then clicks the browser back button, instead of re-loading my app it just displays the json as if I'd gone to `example.com/posts.json` instead of `example.com/posts`. If the user manually reloads the page it loads fine, but it's pretty confusing for the user to see the json.

If I'm on `example.com/posts` and then manually navigate away to say `gmail.com` and click the back button it works fine. It seems to be when a link within my app is clicked that this scenario arises.

Any idea how I can "force" the Backbone app to reload when the back button is clicked to navigate back into my app?

Edit:

Adding my Rails controller - it's hitting the index. But when hitting the back button it seems to be triggering the json vs. the html (though a refresh on the same page causes it to hit the correct html):

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController    
  # GET /surveys
  # GET /surveys.json
  def index
    if cookies[:sample_user_id] && !User.find(cookies[:sample_user_id]).admin?
      if !cookies[:sample_appuser_token] 
        appuser = Appuser.create
        sign_in_appuser appuser
      else
        appuser = current_appuser
      end
      @surveys = User.find(cookies[:sample_user_id]).surveys.includes([:responses => [:choices], :questions => [:answers]])
    else
      if !cookies[:sample_appuser_token] 
        appuser = Appuser.create
        sign_in_appuser appuser
      else
        appuser = current_appuser
      end
      @surveys = Survey.where(status: "Submitted")
      if cookies[:sample_user_id]
        User.find(cookies[:sample_user_id]).surveys.each do |survey|
          @surveys << survey
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

And the index.html.erb view:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header-region"></div>
  <div id="main-region"></div>
  <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer-region"></div>
<div id="dialog-region"></div>
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $(function() {
    Sample.start({
      environment: "<%= Rails.env %>"
    });
  });
<% end %>
```

SurveysRouter:

```
@Sample.module "SurveysApp", (SurveysApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class SurveysApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      ""            : "list"
      ":id"         : "show"
      ":id/take": "take"

  API =
    list: ->
      if $.cookie('sample_user_email') != null
        new SurveysApp.List.Controller
      else
        window.location = "/signin"

    show: (id) ->
      window.fragment = Backbone.history.fragment
      if $.cookie('sample_user_email') != null
        new SurveysApp.Show.Controller
          id: id
      else
        console.log Backbone.history.fragment
        window.location = "/signin" + "#" + window.fragment

    take: (id, survey) ->
      new SurveysApp.Take.Controller 
        id: id 
        survey: survey

    newSurvey: (surveys, survey) ->
      if $.cookie('sample_user_email') != null
        new SurveysApp.New.Controller 
          surveys: surveys
          survey: survey
      else
        window.location = "/signin"

  App.vent.on "survey:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "/" + survey.id
    API.show survey.id

  App.vent.on "new:survey", (surveys, survey) ->
    API.newSurvey surveys, survey

  App.vent.on "take:survey:button:clicked", (survey) ->
    App.navigate "/" + survey.id + "/take"
    API.take survey.id, survey

  App.vent.on "survey:list", ->
    App.navigate "/"
    API.list()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new SurveysApp.Router
      controller: API
```

List controller:

```
@Sample.module "SurveysApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: ->
        surveys = App.request "survey:entities"

        App.execute "when:fetched", surveys, =>
            @layout = @getLayoutView()

            @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @surveyRegion surveys
          @bannerRegion surveys

        @show @layout
        App.request "header:footer"

    surveyRegion: (surveys) ->
      surveyView = @getSurveyView surveys

      @listenTo surveyView, "childview:survey:clicked", (args) ->
        if args.model.get('status') == "Draft"
          App.vent.trigger "new:survey", surveys, args.model
        else
            App.vent.trigger "survey:clicked", args.model


      @listenTo surveyView, "childview:take:survey:button:clicked", (child, args) ->
        survey = args.model 
        survey.set(preview: true)
        App.vent.trigger "take:survey:button:clicked", survey

      @show surveyView, region: @layout.surveyRegion

    getLayoutView: ->
      new List.Layout

    getSurveyView: (surveys) ->
      new List.Surveys
        collection: surveys

    bannerRegion: (surveys) ->
      bannerView = @getBannerView surveys

      @listenTo bannerView, "new:survey:clicked", ->
        App.vent.trigger "new:survey", surveys

      @show bannerView, region: @layout.bannerRegion

    getBannerView: (surveys) ->
      new List.Banner
        collection: surveys
```

And the footer template where the links are:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 align-center">
        <a href="/privacy" id="footer-privacy-link">Privacy</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact us</a>
        <div>©2014 Sample, LLC</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 align-center">
        <a class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sample"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/sample"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a class="email-link" href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see some of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing makes it sounds like `example.com/posts.json` has been added as an entry to the browser's history.  However, AJAX calls don't normally add to the history, so it seems like you must have an errant `router.navigate` or `window.location =` line, or something similar, in your code.  However, without seeing the relevant code it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: I added a bunch of code, but looking through it nothing is really popping out offhand. What you say makes sense though, I'll keep scouring through it as well... :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code you provided either.  One thing you might want to do to facilitate debugging is open up your copy of Backbone and find the `navigate` method of `Backbone.history` (line 1469 in my copy, but your line # may vary), then add a `console.trace()` or `debugger` line to it so that you can tell whenever your code calls it.  If your problem is an errant navigate line, that should help you locate it (and if not, at least you'll know to look for `window.location =` or some manual history manipulation code).